# upload PIL image to azure blob

Tags: python, django, azure, python-imaging-library

I have a Django app that allows users to upload images that are saved in Azure blob storage. When a user uploads an image, I want to both store the original image and create a thumbnail (100x100).

Currently, the site uploads the original from `request.FILES` perfectly, but for creating the thumbnail I can't figure out how to upload to Azure without first saving the edited image to a holding folder, reading that saved image, and then deleting it. That doesn't seem like the most efficient way to save a thumbnail.

Here is the current upload script:

```
# original upload
f = request.FILES['pic']
extension = f.name.split('.')[-1]
new_name, thumb_name = rename_file(extension)
upload(blob_service, 'pic-container', new_name, f)

# create thumbnail
f.seek(0)
im = Image.open(f)
width = im.size[0]
height = im.size[1]
if width > height:
    left_crop = (width - height)/2
    right_crop = (width + height)/2
    cropped = im.crop((left_crop, 0, right_crop, height))
else:
    upper_crop = (height - width)/2
    lower_crop = (height + width)/2
    cropped = im.crop((0, upper_crop, width, lower_crop))
std_size = 100, 100
cropped.thumbnail(std_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

# save to holder, upload thumbnail, then delete from holder
cropped.save('path/to/holder/' + thumb_name)
upload(blob_service, 'media-pic', thumb_name, open('path/to/holder/' + thumb_name))
os.unlink('path/to/holder/' + thumb_name)

# upload script slightly modified from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/#_large-blobs
def upload(blob_service, container_name, blob_name, file_path):
    blob_service.put_blob(container_name, blob_name, '', 'BlockBlob')

    block_ids = []
    index = 0
    with file_path as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(chunk_size)
            if data:
                length = len(data)
                block_id = base64.b64encode(str(index))
                blob_service.put_block(container_name, blob_name, data, block_id)
                block_ids.append(block_id)
                index += 1
            else:
                break

    blob_service.put_block_list(container_name, blob_name, block_ids)
```

If I don't save the thumbnail first and just run `upload(blob_service, 'pic-container', thumb_name, cropped)` I get a pretty uninformative error that just says `__exit__` and points to the line `with file_path as f` in `def upload`.

Is there any way to upload the file directly from `cropped` without having to save the file, either by revising the upload function or by changing `cropped` somehow.

Comment: You can upload Blobs from streams instead of files, so use a MemoryStream instead of a file for the temp destination of cropped. The `Save` converts the byte array into the required image format, so you can't just skip that step.